# Create NAS with Fedora Server

Tags: permissions, ftp, fedora, nas, network-shares

Hey guys, I am new to linux, and wanted to build a NAS box for my Home Network.  I have a server sitting in my house running Fedora 13, and wanted to put a Network Storage Server on it.  I tried Samba, but it didn't have the feature set I wanted, namely close control to users/groups.
Is there another solution that would work well with windows clients?  I want to create a network drive, and allow access to directories on that drive based on users/groups defined on the server..  Also, I would like a public directory, where you wouldn't need to login to access.

I also wanted to add a FTP server, with the users the same as the NAS users, would that be possible?
Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba is what your looking for, but it needs planning and configuration.  Chances are it won't do what you want and how you want it done right after installation.  You want to make sure your windows users have matching linux accounts.  Using the [net](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/net.8.html) command you can create mapping between windows groups and linux groups.  You want to make sure to use the right level of share permissions so that the users/groups are checked against file permissions.

Check out [Samba-by-Example](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-Guide/) for how to setup a small installation.

Comment: Would there be a way to check user/pass against a database, or file?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [OpenFiler](http://www.openfiler.com/). It will give you a nice and easy to use web interface to configure and share your storage.
It also has a simple User/Group managment interface which allows you to restrict access to shares.

Comment: I am looking for an option that I can run in fedora 13, I already have  a HTTP server going.  And I really don't want to fuss with virtualization (doesn't work well with my NIC)

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/) - similar to OpenFiler and another really well-done solution. It can make files available using FTP, CIFS/Samba shares, ssh/scp, rsync, and many other methods.  FreeNAS is also based on FreeBSD, which among other things allows it to use ZFS as a filesystem -- not necessarily a big plus for a home system but a neat feature.

Comment: How would I integrate that into my existing server?